# Setting the lock count to a value greater than 1

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I was reading about reentrancy of intrinsic locks and found the statement I couldn't understand:

> If the same thread acquires the lock again, the count is incremented, and when the owning thread exits the synchronized block, the count is decremented. When the count reaches zero, the lock is released.

What's the purpose of incrementing the count when the thread already holds the lock (the count has been set to 1)? Does this count affect other aspects apart from lock realising?

The following example gives me the count equal to 2 in the parent method. Am I right?

```
class A {
    void a() {
        synchronized (this) {
            // 2 ?
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void b() {
        // 0
        synchronized (this) {
            // 1
            a();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this count programmatically?

EDIT:

I got why we need to increment/decrement the count. I thought we could check a `Thread.holdsLock` and proceed without incrementing if it was true. But during the exiting from "inner" synchronised blocks, we wouldn't know if the current synchronised block is the "outermost" one. Therefore, we wouldn't know when the lock should be released.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: "What's the purpose" Well, when you get to the point of releasing the lock in `a()`, how is it to know whether to "really" release the lock, or if something else is still holding onto the lock? As in, how to know whether `a()` was called directly, or via `b()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner, "how to know whether `a()` was called directly, or via `b()`" - that's the point, but the count does not provide such information, either.

Comment: @AndyTurner, we "really" release the lock when the count is 0. "if something else is still holding onto" - no one can hold onto the lock while we are holding it, can they?

Comment: Well, you don't know if you invoked a or b, that is true. But the synchronization doesn't need to: it just needs to know whether to release the monitor at the end of the synchronized block in `a()`. If `a()` were invoked directly, it should; if it is invoked indirectly via `b()`, it should not. Can you think of an alternative way, other than incrementing a counter on entry and decrementing on exit of a sync block, for it to make this distinction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose is to prevent the lock being released before exiting the outermost synchronized block.